# Dynamic image width in ul/li

Tags: jquery, css

I have code that sets li width dynamically on window resize. It divides 100% with the current number of li tags.

Code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num = $('li').length;
    var width_li = 100 / num;
    $('li').css('width', width_li + '%');
});​
```

Test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jbew7/

How can I make it resize images that's inside the li tags to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS:

```
li img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

100% percent will make sure that image width/height remains same as the width/height of li..